# Search inside circle markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to do a search for markers that are within a circle using as parameters the radius and position of the center of the circle. Someone can help me on how serious this search.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept:

1. make an array of the markers you want to search
2. iterate through the array of markers calculating the distance between each marker and the center point using the [geometry library  computeDistanceBetween()
   function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)
3. compare that distance to the radius of the circle, if it is less than the radius, the marker is inside the circle, otherwise it is outside the circle.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_radiusSearch.html) (with center point from geocoded address)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip, your help was very useful and I got to do what I needed.