# How to detect if a marker is dropped into a fixed-size circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here's what I have tried so far...

I have a circle marker defined like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
  map: map,
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWeight: 3.0, 
    scale: 20 
  }
});
```

I also have a draggable marker. When the draggable marker touches any part of the circle marker, I'd like to change its fillColor.  What I'm struggling with is how to detect if the draggable marker touched any part of the circle marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(dragable_marker, 'drag', function(e) {
  //somehow need to check if e.latLng touched the circle
}
```

The circle marker doesn't even need to be a marker. It can be a plain Circle object.

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    radius : 500,
    fillOpacity : 0,
    strokeOpacity : 0,
    map : map
});
```

Then, I could easily accomplish my goal like this.

```
google.maps.event.addListener( dragable_marker, 'dragend', function(e) {    
    alert(circle.getBounds().contains(e.latLng)); 
});
```

I had originally attempted to solve my problem using a Circle object but then I realized it has no "scale" property nor does it seem to allow me to fix the size of the circle regardless of the map zoom level.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search inside circle markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704148/search-inside-circle-markers/11704394#11704394).  [BTW - a bounds object is square, not circular...]

Comment: possible duplicate also -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766218/detect-if-marker-is-within-circle-overlay-on-google-maps-javascript-api-v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option: use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) computeDistanceBetween function to detect when the marker is inside the circle (it is inside the circle if the distance from the center of the circle to the marker is less than or equal to the radius of the circle).

Code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        radius: 1000,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        map: map
    });
    map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
        var dragable_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: map.getCenter(),
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(dragable_marker, 'dragend', function (e) {
            if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(circle.getCenter(),this.getPosition()) <= circle.getRadius()) {
                circle.setOptions({fillOpacity:0.5,fillColor:"#FF0000"});
            } else  {
              circle.setOptions({fillOpacity:0,fillColor:"#000000"});
            }   
        });
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip. I guess I should've done a better job of explaining all of my requirements. The Circle needs to be of a fixed size even when the zoom level changes. Then your solution (and even my attempted solution) would solve my problem. Any ideas?