# JQuery location picker, how to set maximum allowed distance from start point

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I'm using the JQuery location picker to let the user select a place in the map. The map starts with the pin set to a default location

I'd like to add a maximum distance he/she can select a place with respect to the initial place

How can I do that?
I tried using the `radius` parameter but it only draws a circle around the pin and the user is still free to place the pin whereever he/she wants

that's the picker I'm using:
http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/

Is there some parameter to set or do I need to set the `onChange()` callback with some code to check the distance and reset the pin marker if it's too far away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say keep track of your default location, and its allowed radius.  Use the `onchanged` event listener for when the marker moves, and if it's outside of that radius, then reset it.

You can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775194/492335) to work out if a marker is within a given circle.

It looks like you can get the underlying Google Map object using

```
var map = $('#somecomponent').locationpicker('map');
```

Comment: Cool thanks, since the distance is always less than 30km I could assume the earth flat and work out the distance on my own to save a call to Google api, or is fast enough?

Comment: It should be fast enough